# app crash if there is no data in NSMutableArray * Result1 . [__NSCFConstantString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]:

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

```
    for (NSDictionary *firstDictionaryTemp in alertArray) {
        if ([firstDictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"user_name"]) {
            uId  = [firstDictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"u_id"]; 
            catId  = [firstDictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"cat_id"];
            myDictionary = [firstDictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"topic_detail"];
            for (NSDictionary *secDictionaryTemp in myDictionary) {                      
                if ([secDictionaryTemp  objectForKey:@"description"]) {
                   dictionaryDescription = [secDictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"description"];               
                   [result1 addObject : dictionaryDescription];           
                }
            }
        }
```

...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return result1.count;
    // return [result1 count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath : indexPath];
    UILabel *name2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:30];
    name2.text = [result1 objectAtIndex : indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

{

json
  "topic": [
    {
      "topic_id": "66",
      "cat_id": "74",
      "topic_title": "ssss",
      "userid": "70",
      "total_views": "1",
      "user_name": "abc",
      "topic_detail": [
        {
          "description": "Re",
          "total_reply": 0
        }
      ],
      "is_bookmark": "false"
    },
    {
      "topic_id": "43",
      "cat_id": "74",
      "topic_title": "ee ",
      "userid": "70",
      "total_views": "1",
      "user_name": "abc",
      "topic_detail": [
        {
          "description": "Ee",
          "total_reply": 0
        }
      ],
      "is_bookmark": "false"
    },
    {
      "topic_id": "40",
      "cat_id": "74",
      "topic_title": "demo2",
      "userid": "66",
      "total_views": "1",
      "user_name": "1",
      "topic_detail": [
        {
          "description": "demo2",
          "total_reply": 0
        }
      ],
      "is_bookmark": "false"
    },
    {
      "topic_id": "39",
      "cat_id": "74",
      "topic_title": "demo",
      "userid": "66",
      "total_views": "1",
      "user_name": "1",
      "topic_detail": [
        {
          "description": "demo",
          "total_reply": 0
        }
      ],
      "is_bookmark": "false"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Which line exactly? Guess: In one of your for loops, your think that the object is a Dictionary or an Array, and it's a String. If `myDictionary` is a `NSDictionary` in `for(NSDictionary *secDictionaryTemp in myDictionary)`, `secDictionaryTemp` should be the key

Comment: @Larme please explain it more clearly. Thank You

Comment: Replace `for(NSDictionary *secDictionaryTemp in myDictionary)` with `for(NSString *aKey in myDictionary){NSDictionary *secDictionaryTemp =  myDictionary[aKey]; ... }`. But clearly, if you don't give us what looks like your info, or you can't tell us which line exactly crash, how are we supposed to know where is your issue?

Comment: my app is crashes when there is no data in result1...if there is any data the app is running fine

Comment: @Larme   info {
        "cat_id" = 74;
        "is_bookmark" = false;
        "topic_detail" =         (
                        {
                description = demo;
                "total_reply" = 0;
            }
        );
        "topic_id" = 39;
        "topic_title" = demo;
        "total_views" = 1;
        "user_name" = 1;
        userid = 66;
    }

Comment: @Larme      by  
Replacing for(NSDictionary *secDictionaryTemp in myDictionary) with for(NSString *aKey in myDictionary){NSDictionary *secDictionaryTemp = myDictionary[aKey]; ... } the app still crashing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**If you are moving in else part. then what are you doing in else part. Share the code**

```
if alertArray.count > 0
{
     // execute your code
}
else
{
    // empty array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if alertArray.count > 0
{
     // execute your code
}
else
{
    // empty array
}
```

It simple to check array is empty or not. Hope this will help you.

Comment: my app is crashing in else part if there is no data  in alertarray how i handle that part

Comment: if i'm using if (!([alertArray count] > 0)) only if part is executed . If i'm using if (([alertArray count] > 0)) else part is executed only